# Filter json on React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, getjson

I have to filter this array on 2 ways, one is while the user types and the other is when he clicks on some category, and my code is like this:

https://gist.github.com/pedroapfilho/dbd48b1bf10c4ff625929cb2f67c6b41

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import appslist from "../apps.json";

import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import HeaderSearch from "../components/HeaderSearch/HeaderSearch";
import ListContainer from "../components/ListContainer/ListContainer";
import Pagination from "../components/Pagination/Pagination";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    list: appslist,
    searchfield: "",
    selectedcategory: "",
    currentpage: 1,
    itensperpage: 3
  };

  onSearchChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value });
  };

  onClickCategory = event => {
    this.setState({ selectedcategory: event.target.id });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      list,
      searchfield,
      currentpage,
      itensperpage,
      selectedcategory
    } = this.state;

    let filteredList;

    filteredList = list.filter(list => {
      return list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase());
    });

    filteredList = list.filter(list => {
      return list.categories[0].toLowerCase().includes(selectedcategory.toLowerCase());
    });

    return (
      <div className="flex-container">
        <Sidebar categorylist={list} selectedCategory={this.onClickCategory} />
        <section className="apps-list">
          <HeaderSearch searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
          <ListContainer list={filteredList} />
          <Pagination currentPage={currentpage} itensperpage={itensperpage} />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I kept both `filteredList` there, but only the last one will work

How can I make both works at the same time?

Comment: Have to try to test it with `||` operator like `return condition1 || condition2`?

Comment: What does your `appslist` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the filters:

```
filteredList = list
    .filter(list => list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()))
    .filter(list => list.categories[0].toLowerCase().includes(selectedcategory.toLowerCase()));
```

Or even write it as a single filter:

```
filteredList = list.filter(
    list => list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) &&
            list.categories[0].toLowerCase().includes(selectedcategory.toLowerCase())
);
```

If you need the OR behavior instead of AND, then use the single filter approach and replace `&&` with `||`, obviously.

**Regarding question from comment:**

To use all categories in your filter you may use `some` or `every` (depending on desired logic):

```
filteredList = list.filter(
    list => list.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) &&
            list.categories.some(
                cat => cat.toLowerCase() === selectedcategory.toLowerCase()
            )
);
```

Comment: As you can see, I'm filtering only the first element of the list.categories, how can I pass through all elements on it? It has 1, 2 or 3 elements, like this:

    "categories": ["Voice Analytics", "Reporting", "Optimization"],

Comment: It was working with the chained filter, but seems that If I use the some, nothing appears on the list

Comment: I'm not sure about your structures, it may be that I just misunderstood what is what. But I assume you have knowledge to fix it on your own now.